# How to open a blob object in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, blob, src

How can i display a Blob with pdf content immediately a new tab or have it displayed inline using an iframe?

in chrome and FF i can use something like this

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
$('#uplFrame').attr('src', url);
```

but does not work in IE...i read online that IE is using the following for handeling blobs

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "filename");
```

however this will ask the user if he wants to save or open the file in a new window. is it possible to let the code open the blob this automatically?

or is there a similar solution for the "createObjectURL" that does work for IE?

Comment: I think you'd need to create a temp file on the server to open it in a new window or tab using the browser. To serve a new document your server needs a file to server from, but if you can temporarily cache it on your server you can open the pdf directly in the browser no problem.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` is supported in IE10 and up, but OP doesn't mention IE version.

Answer (score 0):

For security reason and implementation the operation is not allowed in IE so the team build a specific API for asking permissions:

```
  // Save the blob1 content to a file, giving just a "Save" option
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.txt'); 

  // Save the blob2 content to a file, giving both "Save" *and* "Open" options
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob2, 'msSaveBlobOrOpenBlob_testFile.txt');
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And what about just open the file in new tab?

Comment: not working. In IE it is showing access denied exception. I have a blob response object. I have to download that. So creating url like let url = URL.createobjecturl(blob); window.open(url); this is working fine in chrome. But in IE it is not working. So here I had to use msSaveOrOpenBlob. Here file is getting downloaded but it is not able to open automatically in a new tab like chrome. So is there any way to achieve it in Edge. @ Irvin Dominin